# Sql Server Schema Compare Wrong

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-schema

I did a schema compare using visual studio 2017.  The source was my production DB and the target was the repo.  The tool incorrectly told me I had to add a procedure that already existed (see image).  Has it lost sync somehow?  How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: The proc is called usp_opsPlayerTeam_load.sql (why tho?)

Comment: the source and target have the same name isn't that all that matters?

Comment: But they are not the same.

Comment: oh, you mean the .sql suffix?

Comment: Is that not part of the proc name?

Comment: Is the schema the same?

Comment: all the procs have a .sql suffix in the Visual Studio GUI.  Only this proc was identified as a required 'add'

Comment: yes, schema compare found everything the same except this proc

Comment: What happens if you add let it add it?  Do you get two procedures or is the original one overwritten?

Comment: I get two procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click the 'add' file you should get an 'ignore this local item' option.  Go with that.  Another way is to allow the add (like I did above) and just delete the duplicate proc.  After syncing with master repo everything was OK.

I still don't know the root cause, but this did happen after a long time without syncing, so, perhaps syncing the repo more often will prevent this from happening.